# List index out of range - Python

Tags: python, list

```
def Task4():
     import random
     t = True
     list1 = []
     list2 = []
     rand = random.randint(1,6)
     list1.append(rand)
     print(list1)
     for x in range(0,5):
         if list1[0] == (rand):
             list1.pop(0)
         else:
             list2.append(rand)
             print(list2)
             list1.pop(0)
```

Can't workout why `if list1[0] == (rand)`: keeps coming up with a list index out of range.

Comment: You need to check that the first element exists (i.e. the list isn't empty) before indexing it -> `if list1 and list1[0] == rand`

Comment: Debug your code and you'll know why. You can debug it using a pencil and a paper.

Comment: You appended to list1 only one element but in the loop you tried to pop 5 elements.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s see what happens to `list1`:

```
list1 = []
```

Ok, the list is created, and it’s empty.

```
rand = random.randint(1,6)
list1.append(rand)
```

`rand` is added to the list, so at this point `list1 = [rand]`.

```
for x in range(0,5):
```

This will loop four times; so let’s take a look at the first iteration:

```
if list1[0] == (rand):
```

Since `list1 = [rand]`, `list1[0]` is `rand`. So this condition is true.

```
list1.pop(0)
```

The list element at index 0 is removed; since `list1` only contained one element (`rand`), it’s now empty again.

```
for x in range(0,5):
```

Second iteration of the loop, `x` is `1`.

```
if list1[0] == (rand):
```

`list1` is still empty, so there is no index `0` in the list. So this crashes with an exception.

---

At this point, I would really like to tell you how to solve the task in a better way, but you didn’t specify what you are trying to do, so I can only give you a hint:

When you remove items from a list, only iterate for as often as the list contains elements. You can either do that using a `while len(list1)` loop (which will loop until the list is empty), or by explicitely looping over the indexes `for i in len(list1)`. Of course, you can also avoid removing elements from the list and just loop over the items directly using `for x in list1`.

Answer (score 0):

- when x is 0:
  -> you pop the only existing list item, thus the list is empty afterwards
- when x is 1:
  -> you try to access list1[0], which doesn't exist -> list index out of range error

Comment: Dear Downvoter, I'm interested in improving my answers, thus: What's so bad about the answer that you downvoted it? Yes, it could certainly be more complete, but given that it's a simple question, I thought a simple answer would do.

Comment: I think your answer is perfect. Curious about the downvote as well. Anyway, have my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
truth is evident with debugging with print and try except:

def Task4():
    import random
    t = True
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    rand = random.randint(1,6)
    list1.append(rand)
    for x in range(0,5):
        try:
            print("list1 before if and pop",list1)
            if list1[0] == (rand):
                list1.pop(0)
                print("list1 after pop",list1)
            else:
                list2.append(rand)
                print("list2 {}".format(list2))
                list1.pop(0)
        except IndexError as e:
            print("Index Error {}".format(e))
            break

Task4()


list1 before if and pop [3]
list1 after pop []
list1 before if and pop []
Index Error list index out of range
```